# Random Insult Generator (Randomizing Results)

Tags: javascript, random

I've written a random insult generator. It is fine, and works well to what I need. The problem is that when I run the program more than once, the insult is the same every time, unless I copy all the vars again. Here is my code:

```js
var bodyPart = ["face", "foot", "nose", "hand", "head"];
var adjective = ["hairy and", "extremely", "insultingly", "astonishingly"];
var adjectiveTwo = ["stupid", "gigantic", "fat", "horrid", "scary"];
var animal = ["baboon", "sasquatch", "sloth", "naked cat", "warthog"];

var bodyPart = bodyPart[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
var adjective = adjective[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
var adjectiveTwo = adjectiveTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
var animal = animal[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];

var randomInsult = "Your" + " " + bodyPart + " " + "is more" + " " + adjective + " " + adjectiveTwo + " " + "than a" + " " + animal + "'s" + " " + bodyPart + ".";

randomInsult;
"Your nose is more insultingly stupid than a warthog's nose."
randomInsult;
"Your nose is more insultingly stupid than a warthog's nose."
```

What I'm trying to do is when I run `randomInsult;` again, I want a different result.

Comment: You need to use a function. All your doing is picking the variables once and assigning them. Your function would pick a random insult again. Plus you're actually overwriting your array variables when you assign a single result from the array to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function:

```
function generateRandomInsult() {
    // ... all of your existing code ...

    return randomInsult;
}

generateRandomInsult();      // this is what you repeat each time
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, you need to use a function.

```js
var bodyPart = ["face", "foot", "nose", "hand", "head"];
var adjective = ["hairy and", "extremely", "insultingly", "astonishingly"];
var adjectiveTwo = ["stupid", "gigantic", "fat", "horrid", "scary"];
var animal = ["baboon", "sasquatch", "sloth", "naked cat", "warthog"];

var randomInsult = (function() {
  var bp, a, a2, an;
  var bp = bodyPart[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
  var a = adjective[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
  var a2 = adjectiveTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
  var an = animal[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
  var insult = "Your" + " " + bp + " " + "is more" + " " + a + " " + a2 + " " + "than a" + " " + an + "'s" + " " + bp + ".";

  alert(insult);
});

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', randomInsult, false);
```

```html
<button id="test">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like this to select a random bodyPart, adjective, adjectiveTwo and animal at each call.

```
function randomInsult() {
    var bodyPart = ["face", "foot", "nose", "hand", "head"];
    var adjective = ["hairy and", "extremely", "insultingly", "astonishingly"];
    var adjectiveTwo = ["stupid", "gigantic", "fat", "horrid", "scary"];
    var animal = ["baboon", "sasquatch", "sloth", "naked cat", "warthog"];
    var bodyPart = bodyPart[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
    var adjective = adjective[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    var adjectiveTwo = adjectiveTwo[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
    var animal = animal[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
    return "Your" + " " + bodyPart + " " + "is more" + " " + adjective + " " + adjectiveTwo + " " + "than a" + " " + animal + "'s" + " " + bodyPart + ".";
}
```

In your piece of code you are generating the "randomInsult" string only once. It need to be generated at each call, with new random values.
So, simply embed your code in a function.

Call it this way:

```
randomInsult();
```